# Blazor Server side onclick in IE11 not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to get Blazor (server-side) to work with IE11 (it works with Chrome).
But IE 11 doesn't seem to respond to onclick="@ExportExcel".
I have added blazor.polyfill.min.js from https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill but it's doesn't help.
Thanks in advance!

Front end code below.

```
@inject ExcelExportService EES

<div>
    <button onclick="@GetTransferFile">Transfer Excel file</button>
</div>

@functions {

    protected async Task GetTransferFile()
    {
        await EES.TransferFile();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
In _Host.cshtlm
I have added polyfill.min.js as suggested by Issac

```
<body>

    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="blazor.polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>())
    </app>


    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

I now saw in the console log an error message "CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error." I commented out bootstrap just for testing and I still get the error. I am guessing it is the @ before GetTransferFile in onclick that is making a fuzz.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this polyfill: https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/

You should remember that even in server-side execution mode Blazor uses some new JavaScript constructs which are not supported by older browsers, for example promises, Fetch API, etc.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't make a difference unfortunately. I added som more info in my post.

Comment: Are you aware that Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>() prerender your whole Blazor app (in Razor Pages or MVC, I don't know, as I have no access to your whole application). Is this something you want ? Planned ? In any case, this add more complexity to your app, and make it harder to locate the problem. Do you understand what you're doing... Anyhow, server-side Blazor, with the poly-fill recommended by Steve Anderson should work  in IE11

Comment: I am pretty new to this (obviously). But from what I understand is that after the application has rendered the updates are sent with SignalR so that you only update what is changed. I have tried the same with the default template (Blazor server-side) you get when you create a new application. I added the polyfills as here and tried the counter page and I get the same result. The app I have made is the same but withe the forecast and counter page stripped out and the code above added (code behind added of course but I don't reach it in IE).